# postgres procedura script does not read input provided by file.sh

Tags: shell, variables, sh, psql, procedural

I have an Issue running a psql script.

this is the output :

[File.SQL:155: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 10:       date_temp_Ale INTEGER := :'param_date';](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPDDr.png)

i have a file.sh that  is calling the "File.sql" with and Input varible.
here is the line that callsthe sql script:

[line in file.sh:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEqfm.png)

```
echo le numero des parametres est bien 7 
psql -v PGPASSWORD=$MDP -h $IP_MACHINE -f $FIC_REQ_SQL -v param_date=20180101  -U  $UTILISATEUR -d $NOM_BDD -p $PORT > $FIC_LOG_EXEC_TMP 2>&1  


echo Done in $FIC_LOG_EXEC_TMP
```

here is the line in the psql script:
[line in file.sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1noz.png)"

```
--- UT 48  PURGE DES TRACES
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on

BEGIN; -- DEBUT DE TRANSACTION

 DO $$ 
DECLARE
  num_tra_err_id RECORD;
  num_trace_composant RECORD;
  num_trace_fonctionnelle RECORD;
  num_message_id RECORD;
  num_metadonnees_id RECORD;
  num_Process_id RECORD;
  datediff integer;
  date_temp_Ale INTEGER := :'param_date';      

  Max_days  integer := 180;
  --date_limite varchar := &1;
BEGIN
```

i also tried to use the command " --set " in the file.sh but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing you probably don't want those single quotes around `param_date` on that line.

Comment: hi Shawn, thans for the reply, 
I tried both with single quote and also without but the error persist.

Comment: i figured out that if i retrieve the variable before the DO $$, then I can correctly access it, but if i do the same inside the the DO $$ then I get the error !
now i am still facing the issue of how to use the variable (which i retrieved before the DO $$), inside the DO $$

Comment: what i did it is :  SELECT  :param_date::date into temp_val;
but now I cannot use the variable temp_val inside the DO $$
because i get an error "relation "temp_val" already exists"

Answer (score 0):

i found a slution:

the DO statement isolate the inner code from the outer code.

to pass the info we need to store it as psql variable as follow

```
select set_config('psql.param_date', :param_date, false);

BEGIN; -- DEBUT DE TRANSACTION

  DO 

  $$ 

    DECLARE

      limit_date varchar = current_setting('psql.param_date');
```